# How to update/change system date time format in regional and language options in control panel using code?

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for code in .NET (C#)
to change the system date/time format in Regional Options of the Control Panel
for Windows XP.

Comment: Are you sure you want to change it globally, for all applications on the computer?

Comment: OB Old New Thing link [Don't use global state to manage a local problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx). If it doesn't apply, apologies, but it's frequently seen.

Answer (score 2):

To change date-time format take a look at this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/263d73b2-8611-4398-9f09-9aa76bbf325e/

You basically need to use native Win API method `SetLocaleInfo`.

Comment: OP wants to change the display format of the date/time, not set the date/time.

Comment: @Gabe - well, this is not what post said originally. It said 'how to change system datetime'. It didn't say 'format'.

Comment: Yes, the post was a bit more confusing before I edited it. Since the word "format" is in the title and the format is what you change in the Regional Options control panel, I'm fairly certain that's what the OP meant.

Comment: i will be used this syntax it will be run but it not changed the format it will be display the extra symbol in the time like 09::::00::::00

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to programatically change regional settings permanently, not just for your current process.

The information you need is stored in the registry.  For the current user under the key:

```
HKCU\Control Panel\International
```

And the default for new users or users without a profile:

```
HKEY_USERS\.Default\Control Panel\International
```

You could change the registry values programatically, then broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message as described in [a response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052218/registry-settings-immediate-effect-using-c).

Comment: is it possible to change the setting to only my process because datetime variable take system format & i want stored this date to the mysql ,MYSQL accept only the 'mm-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss' format it will not accept the 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt' this format i want to change this format then stored in to database in datetime format

Comment: i will be update the this registry HKEY_USERS\.Default\Control Panel\International this change will be not affected in the regional settings in control panel

Comment: @vrushali - is your *actual* problem about getting datetime values in your application to insert correctly into a MySQL database? If so, why didn't you ask that instead? It's got very different answers, and you don't end up breaking the users machine.

Comment: when this key updated HKEY_USERS\.Default\Control Panel\International

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change temporarily the regional settings you can use following code:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo oldCI = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

...

YOUR CODE

...

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI;
```

TO find out which regional setting is best, check:

[CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx)

[More reading on System.Globalisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
public void changedatetimeformat()
{
    RegistryKey regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\International", true);
    regkey.SetValue("sShortDate", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    regkey.SetValue("sLongDate", "dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Then 
Restart Your System

Comment: Please try formatting your answer for better readability and explain what your code does. You might also take a look at [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write better answers.