# Change EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke registry value and make TabTip.exe to accept change

Tags: c#, windows, registry, on-screen-keyboard

Windows 10  has setting "Show the touch keyboard when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard attached", which allows Windows to show touch keyboard whenever you touch text box.

As Windows handles this logic rather poorly (it is easily broken in WPF applications), I would like to turn off this option for my application, which I'm trying to do by changing registry value `EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke`, corresponding to this option (simple `Registry.SetValue` method). But there is an issue - touch keyboard application `TabTip.exe` for some reason doesn't really "hook up" changes in registry, and keeps showing touch keyboard until it is restarted. And vice versa - once I'm restoring registry value, I need to restart application to apply change.

And this is where main issue of such approach appears - with auto-invoke option enabled, once TabTip process starts, it immediately shows keyboard. Obviously I would not like such visual side-effects for my application logic.

Another point is that while changing this setting in usual way, via Windows Settings application, TabTip or any related applications or services are not restarted. Which means Settings application somehow manages to update TabTip process. I would really like to figure how it does this, and if I can reproduce same behavior in C#, but I have no idea how.

So, my question is - how can I programmatically change either `EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke` registry value or "Show the touch keyboard when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard attached" Windows option, and make TabTip application to accept this change, without any possible visual side-effects?

**UPD:**

I know that it is possible to make keyboard to ignore text box by creating custom text box with specific automation peer, but this would require to replace all text boxes in entire application, and always keep in mind that we need to use new text boxes, so this is not viable solution. I've tried to remove possibility to get automation peers for children of main window as well, but that doesn't work.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/1052715/2830850?

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work as well.

Comment: Most places I checked, everyone is killing the exe and doing it, and I don't have a windows system to check other workarounds

Comment: Apparently we will go with this as well. This was my last resort, but apparently there is no other way at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I looked at lot of different implementations of the same

https://github.com/maximcus/WPFTabTip/blob/65b58e1900d3c21c9ea684e9f882088fe821586b/WPFTabTip/TabTip.cs

https://github.com/zhangtx2812/NewClient/blob/851f6dd8bc9c6389b70c7b5cd9384617a62a274e/Client.Helpers/Utils/KeyboardHelper.cs

https://github.com/Anneliese1989/Examintion/blob/2f974312d1ce0452a018bcaecf7bda753c818d9e/WPFTabTip/TabTip.cs

https://github.com/TransposonY/GestureSign/blob/11395ba6f18ea39b86f8e0a586b10a43f3c27568/GestureSign.CorePlugins/TouchKeyboard/TouchKeyboardUI.xaml.cs

https://github.com/microdee/mp.essentials/blob/d5832dee693839d55157d287d2459760b90b1d05/windows/WindowsLaunchOSKNode.cs

and most case one kills the process using

```
foreach (Process tabTipProcess in Process.GetProcessesByName(TabTipProcessName))
    tabTipProcess.Kill();
```

or close the keyboard using

```
void closeKeyboard()
{
    uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 274;
    uint SC_CLOSE = 61536;
    IntPtr KeyboardWnd = FindWindow("IPTip_Main_Window", null);
    PostMessage(KeyboardWnd.ToInt32(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, (int)SC_CLOSE, 0);
}
```

So, I think what you have already are the best choices known

Comment: That's not exactly an answer I was looking for (and nothing I haven't knew already), but, I suppose, I will mark it as answer, so you can get bounty as reward for your research. PS. Recent update for Windows 10 made keyboard less junky for WPF applications, so I might just work with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a shot in the dark for you...

Here's one way that it is possible TabTip is notified of registry changes by Windows Settings but not by you:   If TabTip is using something like the WMI [RegistryKeyChangeEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393040(VS.85).aspx) class internally, it's possible that the TabTip application is only monitoring the parent registry key and not monitoring the key value you're actually changing (which is why TapTip not updated when you change the value).  But, the Windows Settings application could be setting the whole `key` (and it's corresponding `valueName` and `value`) via something like [SetExpandedStringValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393299(v=vs.85).aspx), which would trigger the key change that TabTip could be watching.

The way to test for this would be to set the `key`, `valueName`, and `value` all at once programmatically, instead of just setting the `value`.

Comment: Sadly, it seems to be not the case. From what I see, `SetExpandedStringValue` basically creates `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type value in corresponding key, so using it with parameters corresponding to TabTip auto invoke just replaces old `REG_DWORD` value with new `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value. And worst of all - TabTip doesn't care about this operation, and keeps working as before. Even settings application doesn't properly hook up the change. I've tried to use `SetDWORDValue` instead, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not a great solution, but you could attempt to hook up to the showing event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane

And immediately call a TryHide in the event of a show event to suppress it.

Comment: I'm using WPF application. It is possible to use InputPane from WPF app to find touch keyboard size, but neither TryShow/TryHide nor visibility events are actually working. That was one of first things I've tried when started to work with Win10 touch keyboard.

Comment: Ah I see misread the comment. Thanks for letting me know you tried.